# keypress shift plus any number

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

According to [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) the code value of number `1` is `49` but below code doesn't run properly. In console when user presses number `1` this can be seen:

```
"keyCode": 49,
"key": "1",
"charCode": 49,
"char": undefined,
"which": 49,
```

meaning the code for 1 is indeed `49` but if combine with shift it is not showing any in console.

When pressing `shift + 1` on the other hand gives:

```
"key": "!",
"code": "Digit1",
"location": 0,
"ctrlKey": false,
"shiftKey": true,
"altKey": false,
"metaKey": false,
"repeat": false,
"isComposing": false,
"charCode": 33,
"keyCode": 33,
"which": 33,
```

> What is the correct way to detect keypress of shift + any number?

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
  //console.log(event);
  if (event.which === 49 && event.shiftKey) {
    console.log("pressed shift + 1")
  }
  if( event.which === 65 && event.shiftKey ) {
        alert('you pressed SHIFT+A');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `keypress` event treats shift + 1 as an exclamation mark, hence `which == 33`. If you want to test whether the 1/! key was pressed try the `keydown` or `keyup` events instead.

Comment: @nnnnnn why is that? which is better to use between `keypress and keydown`? also why is letters not affected by this changing in code when i tried `shift + a`,  `if( event.which === 65 && event.shiftKey ) {` works. unfortunately i think shift plus number is a better suit for my project because I need these short to point to pages.

Comment: With `keypress`, letters *are* affected. If you press the "a" key without shift you get `which` of `97` (i.e., lowercase "a"). The `keypress` event has more of a focus on characters rather than keys. If you are talking shortcuts then probably `keydown` would be better than `keyup` - up to you.

Comment: @nnnnnn i updated the demo with a if else for letter a and it works. using `code 65 for a` which is it the link of list.

Comment: Yes, 65 is for a capital "A", which is what you get if holding shift. But as I said, 97 is for lowercase "a". If you just want to test for the key itself use `keydown`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes just `shift + any number` can you provide answer? also tell why it is changing i dont really understand why it does that. it seems I dont understand the difference between `keypress and keydown` yet

Comment: Because the keypress event is focused on the generated *character*. "1" and "!" and "a" and "A" are (obviously) all different characters. If your focus is on the actual key then use the keydown event.

Comment: that explanation is clear as water. can you provide it as answer so this OP will be closed? I will accept it

Comment: using keydown instead of keypress i can see all the right data including `keyCode: 49` and `shift: true`

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same thing. Using `keydown` wasn't enough though. We'd already converted all our codebase to check `event.key`, as that's the recommended property to use. (`which`, `keyCode`, and `charCode` are all deprecated.)

But in one place we had to be able to detect `Shift + 1`, so for that I used:

```
var expectedKey '1'; // or w, or W, etc.
if (event.shiftKey) {
    if (event.key == expectedKey || event.code == 'Digit' + expectedKey) {
```

`event.code` provides the physical key that was pressed, rather than the character that the keyboard layout interprets that as.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Thanks for this! I had never realized that `event.code` existed, and was different from `event.keyCode`.